# What is the suggested migration route from mssql extension in php

Tags: php, sql-server, migration, pdo

This has probably been asked before but I can't find it anywhere.

I have just found out that the mssql extension has been dumped from php (I know it was a while ago I'm a bit slow).

I have a legacy app that is using it and all the mssql_query etc functions.  I'm wondering what the suggested route is?

- PDO?
- Microsofts Driver
- Move to another DB?

I'm not entirely averse to moving to mysql since everytime I have to move boxes I have huge issues getting MSSQL to work correctly with php.  Is old mysql extension still supported or do I need to move to PDO anyway?

Is there an easy way to move to PDO?  Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO is recommended anyway to abstract to DB connections, so if you go to MySQL I'd highly recommend using it. If you're on windows environments connecting to SQL server then the MS SQLSRV library is likely a good route to take. I have used the odbc_* functions when dealing MSSQL in the past with no problems, including calling stored procs as well as my own queries.

Another DB which didn't have OS lock in would be a good move too though. MySQL is ubiquitous, however don't rule out alternatives without doing some research first.